# Transact SQL - How do I include an IF..THEN or CASE...WHEN within a Function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am relatively new to SQL but have good programming experience behind me. I have a piece of code that was given to me to create a 'Function' which returns values into a table. However, I have a problem with NULLS when the code is trying to compare 2 sets of data to give a percentage difference. Where one set of data is all NULLS then the Join cannot happen on the INSERT so it returns nothing although really there is a difference of 100%. I want to add in an IF statement so that if the count of one of the sets of data is zero (they were all nulls) then it defaults a value and if there are 2 genuine sets of data then it joins the 2 and calculates? Hope this explains it enough. Below is most of the code - DS1VALS or DS2VALS could return nothing if there is NO data. I have tried pretty much everything around this area to add an IF EXISTS or ISNULL but nothing works. I did get a message that suggested that a FUNCTION cannot return the answer to the IF etc??? 
Thanks.

```
-- get the PeriodicDataElementInstanceID for the datasources that we're using
select @DataSource1_PDEIID = PeriodicDataElementInstanceID
from PeriodicDataElementInstance
where Name = @DS1

select @DataSource2_PDEIID = PeriodicDataElementInstanceID
from PeriodicDataElementInstance
where Name = @DS2

-- get the start and end date of the periods in the past that we are checking.
-- these are based on the Calendar, calendar period type, and system start date set in the Universal
-- system options.
select @fromDate = StartDate
from dbo.GetPeriodsDateByPeriodsOffset(@X)

select @toDate = EndDate
from dbo.GetPeriodsDateByPeriodsOffset(@Y)

select @fromDate2 = StartDate 
from dbo.GetPeriodsDateByPeriodsOffset(@XX) 

select @todate2 = EndDate 
from dbo.GetPeriodsDateByPeriodsOffset(@YY) 

;with
DS1VALS (EI, Value) as
(select pds.EndItemID, sum(pd.value)
from PeriodicDataStream pds 
join PeriodicData pd on pd.PeriodicDataStreamID = pds.PeriodicDataStreamID
where pds.PeriodicDataElementInstanceID = @DataSource1_PDEIID
and pd.PeriodDate between @fromDate and @todate
group by pds.EndItemID),
DS2VALS (EI, Value) as
(select pds.EndItemID, sum(pd.value)
from PeriodicDataStream pds 
join PeriodicData pd on pd.PeriodicDataStreamID = pds.PeriodicDataStreamID
where pds.PeriodicDataElementInstanceID = @DataSource2_PDEIID
and pd.PeriodDate between @fromDate2 and @todate2 
group by pds.EndItemID)

--select * from DS1VALS ds1
--join DS2VALS ds2 on ds1.EI = ds2.EI

Insert into @Results
select ds1.EI,  
    case 
    when (convert(numeric(19,9),ds1.Value) <> 0)
    then (convert(numeric(19,9),ds2.Value) / convert(numeric(19,9),ds1.Value) - 1) * 100
    else 9999999999
    end
from DS1VALS ds1
join DS2VALS ds2 on ds1.EI = ds2.EI
where convert(numeric(19,9),ds1.Value) <> convert(numeric(19,9),ds2.Value);

Return
End
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume the following:

- Number2/Number1 = fraction/percent
- 0/Number1 = 0 (same result as Number2/Number1, so no special case needed)
- Number2/0 = error, you want to show 9999999999
- NULL/Number1 = 0
- Number2/NULL = same as divide by zero

As you can see from the above, if either side is NULL, it is treated the same as zero. Your solution is to convert NULL to zero:

```
CASE
    WHEN ISNULL(convert(numeric(19,9),ds1.Value), 0) = 0 THEN 9999999999
    ELSE 
    (
        ISNULL(convert(numeric(19,9),ds2.Value), 0) 
        / convert(numeric(19,9),ds1.Value) 
        - 1
    )
    * 100
END
```

UPDATE: based on feedback, the following will also need changing:

```
FROM DS1VALS ds1
FULL OUTER JOIN DS2VALS ds2 ON ds1.EI = ds2.EI
WHERE ISNULL(convert(numeric(19,9),ds1.Value), 0) <> ISNULL(convert(numeric(19,9),ds2.Value), 0);
```

Note that the join is now a `FULL OUTER JOIN`. This will match rows where it can, include just the left side where there's no matching right side, and just the right side where there's no matching left side.

You have to be careful that your `WHERE` clause doesn't force your join to work like an `INNER JOIN` though.

Comment: thanks for your reply and I like your logic but I think the problem here is that the sub-query for DS2VALS has NO records so the 'join' on the Insert never happens and the Case statement is never evaluated? I tried your code and got the same results as before. I really need to be able to say......'IF select Count(*) from DS2VALS =0' then INSERT with defaults ELSE INSERT as above with a join?? Not sure whether my logic is correct on the join....I come from an AS400, RPG world which is very different to this!! Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: If that is the case, change it to a `LEFT JOIN`, then everything on the right will be `NULL` if no record is found. You will need to wrap the expressions in the `WHERE` clause in `ISNULL` to prevent issues too, I'll update the code.

Comment: Hi, again, thanks for your time on this. I had thought about a left join but again I don't know whether DS1VALS will be NULL or DS2VALS will be NULL so I can't really specify which join to use. That's why I wanted to test DS1VALS and DS2VALS and then use an IF to choose the correct join. However, when I place any code in between the ';with' and the Insert then it 'loses' the connection to DS1VALS and DS2VALS and no longer recognises them. To be honest I don't think it can be done within the FUNCTION?

Comment: Ahh, you need `FULL OUTER JOIN` then. Updating answer.

Comment: That's brilliant.......and yet seems so simple! I had to add a 'Select ISNULL(ds1.EI,ds2.EI),' to make sure that I had readable info for the NULLS in DS1VALS but your solution returned all the records required..Really appreciate your help.